# Apache "Restart" Fails following Go-Daddy SSL Certificate Installation

Tags: 14.04, apache2, mod-ssl

I've followed [digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority) and seem to be hitting a problem at the last hurdle.

I've configured my 000-default.conf as per the instructions in the link and get the following error message when I run the sudo command to stop and then restart the apache service.

---

Output of config test was:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 35 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt' does not exist or is empty
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

---

The `SSLCertificateFile` detailed on line 35 makes does not reference to the `/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt` file but rather states the following: -

```
SSLCertificateFile /home/ridgejason/exampledomain.org.crt
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The error is not in `000-default.conf ` but in in `default-ssl.conf`